# cannot run X apps in a docker container, in Archlinux host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, x11, archlinux, x11-forwarding

I have a Dockerfile which enables me to run X apps.
It works perfectly in an Ubuntu host, but not in a Archlinux host:

```
FROM mascip/archlinux:2014.12.09

# To avoid a bug with the filesystem: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/base/arch/
RUN sed 's/^CheckSpace/#CheckSpace/g' -i /etc/pacman.conf

# BROWSERS
RUN pacman --noconfirm -S nvidia-libgl && pacman --noconfirm -S leafpad

# NON-ROOT USER
# Replace you uid, gid, and username
RUN pacman --noconfirm -S sudo
RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && the_user="abla" && \
    the_home="/home/${the_user}" && \
    the_capital_user=$(echo $the_user | sed 's/./\U&/') && \
    mkdir -p $the_home && \
    echo "${the_user}:x:${uid}:${gid}:${the_capital_user},,,:/${the_home}:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
    echo "${the_user}:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
    echo "${the_user} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/${the_user} && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${the_user} && \
    chown ${the_user}:${the_user} -R ${the_home}

# Replace username and home
ENV USER abla
ENV HOME /home/abla
WORKDIR /home/abla

USER abla

CMD /usr/bin/leafpad
```

In order to run it, I do:

```
$ docker build -t a1 .

$  docker run -ti \
    -e DISPLAY -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.Xauthority -v /home/user/.Xauthority:/tmp/.Xauthority -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    a1 leafpad
```

which works in Ubuntu (a Leafpad window opens), but not in Arch where I get:

```
leafpad: Cannot open display:
```

I need to get this working soon. Any ideas to investigate further would be well appreciated.

PS: I have a similar Docker container which runs leafpad in a Ubuntu container; the problem is exactly the same for that container too.
PPS: the Dockerfile stems from here: [url]http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/[/url]

Comment: what shows `docker exec -it leafpad env` , is DISPLAY defined ?

Comment: It is defined:

    `$ docker exec -it a11 env`

shows (I don't think I can use newlines in a comment...) :

    `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

    HOSTNAME=c2f7459e15d0

    TERM=xterm

    DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

    XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.Xauthority

    HOME=/home/abla

    USER=abla`

Answer (score 0):

try using

xhost +

then mess with the xauth stuff